# Wordpress doesn't include css

Tags: php, css

I want load a custom css in the `index.php` file, this is my code in `function.php`

```
if(! function_exists('basictheme_styles_scripts')) {
    function basictheme_styles_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_style('basictheme-opensans', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'basictheme', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','basictheme_styles_scripts');
```

but perhaps something is wrong, beacause my index doesn't load it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed the relevant code inside `function.php`, but WordPress loads `functions.php`

You're also missing some indenting which makes syntax errors much more likely to occur, and you can save some typing by using `get_stylesheet_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css'`